# corPlot difficulties: cex.axis only affects y-axis, not x-axis font size + significance asterisks display at single panel

Tags: r, correlation

I've been using corPlot from the psych package for my correlation plots since it offers better options for me in terms of plot layouts than corrplot. A couple months ago, both y-axis and x-axis label font sizes responded to the "cex.axis" argument. However, now the x-axis font size won't change. In addition, I only need the lower panel and now it displays significance asterisk symbols on both panels, something that didn't happen a few months ago. Anyone who know about this or has corPlot changed?

This is the code I've been using:

```
correlationplot.cog.mnt <- data[,c(4,7:8,13,19:20,24:32,42:51)]
corr.test(correlationplot.cog.mnt,method = "spearman", use = "pairwise")
corrvalues.cog <-corr.test(correlationplot.cog.mnt,method = "spearman", use = "pairwise")$r
pvalues.cog <-corr.test(correlationplot.cog.mnt,method = "spearman", use = "pairwise")$p

par(bty="n")
par(oma=c(1, 0.05, 1, 0.05))
format.pval(c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001))
gr <- colorRampPalette(c("#70030e", "#ab5620", "white","#0270b0", "#010145"))
corPlot(corrvalues.cog, cex = 0.5, cex.axis = 0.5, xlas = 2, upper = FALSE, pval= pvalues.cog, stars = TRUE, colors= T, gr=gr)
```

I've tried cex.names already but got the error that this isn't a graphical parameter...